# How to change cellarray size and maintain a specific order of data?

Tags: matlab

I have a bunch of 2 sets of time series data in cellarrays (2x1 cell) to which I want to apply corrcoef.

When both sets of data encompass the same amount of years and are the same size, I have no problem applying corrcoef after removing NaNs by interpolation.

But some of the sets are different sizes.

For example the first cell in set1 is 1x552 and the second cell is 1x576 (2 more years of monthly data at the beginning of the series).  Because the data are time series I need to ensure that the relationship between data and data year is maintained when I resize.  The year data is in another array.
I would like to be able to check what years are missing from the smaller cellarray and add these (maybe as means) in the right spot so that it becomes the same size as the larger cellarray.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You want to have a look at `interp1`. Say you have a time-series with times `t` and values `v`, where:

- `t` is a `Nt x 1` column vector with the sampling times sorted in ascending chronological order;
- `v` is a `Nt x Nc` matrix of associated values across `Nc` channels at each time;

then you can interpolate new values at timepoints `new_t` simply with

```
new_v = interp1( t, v, new_t );
```